# Google Streetview API - Getting heading of streetview

Tags: google-maps

When you get an image from the Google Maps Streetview -

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/index.html

Using the syntax:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false
```

It will load an image with the camera pointed at the object.
The documentation states:

> heading (optional) indicates the compass heading of the camera. Accepted values are from 0 to 360 (both values indicating North, with 90 indicating East, and 180 South). **If no heading is specified, a value will be calculated that directs the camera towards the specified location**, from the point at which the closest photograph was taken.

I'd like to the compass heading of the camera when I load an image?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the heading of a street using Street view API and use the heading value to fetch the image that points towards the street. Here is my solution.

[Google Street View heading issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900173/google-street-view-heading-issue/11950935#11950935)

After getting the heading value, just call the street view image API with that value.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this from the Street View Image service, but if you're using the JavaScript [Street View API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html), you can [get it from Panoramas](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StreetViewPanorama) that you're looking at.