# Google Street View heading issue

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-street-view

I'm working in a project where I need to show google map street view heading towards road.

I've set the heading: 0 for the panorama object. But for different location it shows the heading differently. for example in some cases it shows heading towards street, for some locations it shows heading towards home.

```
panorama = theMap.getStreetView();
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>, <?php echo $lng; ?>););
panorama.setPov({
    heading: 0,
    zoom:1,
    pitch:0
});
```

If there any way  can fix the heading towards street for all post codes?

Thanks

Comment: [0 is north](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPov).  You need to either know or calculate the direction to the road to make this work.  Since a "postcode" is not a physical location, that will be difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I have an idea.. if I can set the heading towards the next panaroma (I can get a unique panaroma id) then it will head towards the street. Have you got any idea how to implement that?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData) is always a useful resource.  I would investigate the getLinks() function of [google.maps.StreetViewPanorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found a very easy solution..

For the street view there's two links to navigate, that point towards street. I just read those heading and set the street view POV towards that direction. Here's full code.

```
var panoramaOptions = {
    position: langlongObj,
    visible: true
};
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), panoramaOptions);
map.setStreetView(panorama);

google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'links_changed', function() {
    var links =  panorama.getLinks();

    panorama.setPov({                   
        heading: links[0].heading,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: 1
    });
});
```